# Using Image for Menu Item Without Text

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to set an image as a menu item, but without the text of the original item. **The problem is I cannot access the sub-menu on hover.** There is no hover action at all. I'm using WordPress.

```
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-56 {
background: url(http://lexhabitat.org/wp-content/themes/lexingtonhabitatforhumanity/img/ReStore-menu-ico.png)no-repeat center;
text-indent: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
width: 55px;
margin: 0px 15px !important;
}
```

[Example Site - See Primary Horizontal Menu](http://iemajen.com/lexingtonhabitatforhumanity/)

[Screen Shot Example](http://iemajen.com/LHFH-menu-image-stack-exchange.jpg)

Comment: Try removing `overflow:hidden;` from your css code above ;)

Comment: Yes! It works! I just have to some other CSS and - problem solved. Cursor, some padding, and anchor color - Thank you so much. I got this,

Comment: I've put this as an answer so you can accept it if you wish :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `overflow:hidden;` from your css. From [W3 site](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp):

> The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

Since you put the `overflow:hidden` on your container, the submenus will be hidden in the overflow and therefore not visible. Removing it will show your menu children.

EDIT: You also text indented the menu text on this custom menu, to remove it from view, which is not a good solution. Remove the text indent, and since it has a special class on it, you can easily target it

```
li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-56 > a {
    color:transparent!important;

}

li.menu-item.menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-56 > a:hover {
    color:transparent!important;
}
```

If this is for a client, then it's a 'good enough' solution, since you are targeting a specific class that was created from the wordpress (`..menu-item-56`). In general if I was doing this for a theme, I'd probably look into changing a menu walker to incorporate an image menu.

Comment: Thank you, dingo_d. That does the trick, but it looks like I'm facing another issue. If I have the overflow removed, it will then show the `text-indent: 100%;` and that screws everything up as well. Maybe there is a better work-around?

All I need to do  is hide the text so it doesn't affect the background image, keeping all elements intact.

Comment: That is awesome. Very simple. I didn't think that I could make the color transparent! Good to know. Thank you so much!!!